# How can I set *.xsh filetypes as python?

Tags: vimrc

I am trying to have `set filetype=python` automatically executed when I open a file ending in .xsh.  However when I try it and then run the command `set ft?` it always shows me the file as `xonsh`.  This is correct but the xonsh filetype doesn't support automatic indenting like `python` filetype does.

I have tried putting the following in my ~/.vimrc file

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.xsh setf python
```

but it is always somehow getting overridden as xonsh type.

Any thoughts on how I can make this setting stick on startup?

Comment: Check the help at `:h new-filetype`

Comment: The filetype `xonsh` and the extension `.xsh` are not recognised by Vim out of the box so we are missing some context, here. You probably have some custom plugin for `xonsh` that we don't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.xsh` files are not recognized by a standard Vim or Neovim installation, so it looks like you installed a plugin for that at some point ([xonsh-vim](https://github.com/abhishekmukherg/xonsh-vim)?) Try removing the plugin.

Or, if you want to keep the plugin, you can use something like this to override it:

```
autocmd Filetype xonsh set filetype=python
```

Or to have both filetypes applied:

```
autocmd Filetype xonsh set filetype=python.xonsh
```

Comment: I had completely forgotten I had installed some files under ~/.vim directory from some github project that was supposed to support xonsh.  I removed those files and now the autocmd is working correctly.